# foreach statement count

Tags: c#

How do I get the count/number of execution of a `foreach` statement?

For example if I have a statement like this:

```
test.testMethod.Foreach(x => x.testMethod2.Add(test_arg));
```

I want to know the number of times `Add` has run, basically the number of `x`.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: What are `test`, `testMethod`, and `testMethod2`? Can't you do `test.testMethod.Length`?

Comment: I think the only way to get the current index is a `for` loop.

Comment: Note you can use `AddRange` to add each item from a sequence.  It's more efficient than just `Add` as it can reduce the number of times the internal buffer needs to be resized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `Foreach` in `LINQ`. You are talking about [`List<T> ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx).
Use `Count` on `List<T>` to get number of items

Answer (score 1):

Simply [`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx):

```
test.testMethod.Count()
```

Comment: When talking about pure IEnumerable<T>, I'd use just a foreach loop or .ToList() to prevent multiple enumeration

Answer (score 1):

I think you need your item index in each iteration:

```
  var index = 0;
  test.testMethod.Foreach(x =>{ 
     ++index;   
     x.testMethod2.Add(test_arg);
  });
```

Comment: This assumes `Foreach` doesn't do any parallell stuff

Comment: @DavidS. Well, this isn't `Parallel.ForEach`.  What indication do you have that it is run in parallel?  If it is in fact parallel, you would only need to modify it to use `Interlocked.Increment`.

Comment: @DavidS. Right, it's not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Servy there is no indication, for or against, so I'm simply stating there's no guarantee unless we see the implementation of `Foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multiline lambda that includes a count increment.